# Pandas: Splitting and editing file based on dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to pandas and having a little trouble solving the following problem. 
I have two files I need to use to create output. The first file contains a list on functions and associated genes.
an example of the file (with obviously completely made up data)

```
File 1:

Function    Genes
Emotions    HAPPY,SAD,GOOFY,SILLY
Walking    LEG,MUSCLE,TENDON,BLOOD
Singing    VOCAL,NECK,BLOOD,HAPPY
```

I'm reading into a dictionary using:

```
from collections import *

FunctionsWithGenes = defaultdict(list)

def read_functions_file(File):
    Header = File.readline()
    Lines = File.readlines()
    for Line in Lines:
        Function, Genes = Line[0], Line[1] 
        FunctionsWithGenes[Function] = Genes.split(",") # the genes for each function are in the same row and separated by commas
```

The second table contains all the information I need in a .txt file that contains a column of genes 
for example:

```
chr    start    end    Gene    Value   MoreData
chr1    123    123    HAPPY    41.1    3.4
chr1    342    355    SAD    34.2    9.0
chr1    462    470    LEG    20.0    2.7
```

that I read in using:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_table(File)
```

The dataframe contains multiple columns one of which is "Genes". This column can contain a variable number of entries. I would like to split the dataframe by the "Function" key in the FunctionsWithGenes dictionary. So far I have:

```
df = df[df["Gene"].isin(FunctionsWithGenes.keys())] # to remove all rows with no matching entries
```

Now I need to somehow split the dataframe based on gene functions. I was thinking perhaps to add a new column with gene function, but not sure if that would work since some genes can have more than one function.

Comment: Can you add a brief demo piece of each file's contents?  It helps a lot to understand exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your last line of code:

```
 df = df[df["Gene"].isin(FunctionsWithGenes.keys())]
```

since the keys of `FunctionsWithGenes` are the actual functions (`Emotions` etc...) but the genes columns have the values. The resulting `DataFrame` would always be empty.

If I understand you correctly, you would like to split the table up so that all the genes belonging to a function are in one table, if that's the case, you could use a simple dictionary comprehension, I set up some variables similar to yours:

```
>>> for function, genes in FunctionsWithGenes.iteritems():
...     print function, genes
... 
Walking ['LEG', 'MUSCLE', 'TENDON', 'BLOOD']
Singing ['VOCAL', 'NECK', 'BLOOD', 'HAPPY']
Emotions ['HAPPY', 'SAD', 'GOOFY', 'SILLY']
>>> df
    Gene  Value
0  HAPPY   3.40
1    SAD   4.30
2    LEG   5.55
```

Then I split up the the `DataFrame` like this:

```
>>> FunctionsWithDf = {function:df[df['Gene'].isin(genes)]
...     for function, genes in FunctionsWithGenes.iteritems()}
```

Now `FunctionsWithDf` is a dictionary which maps `Function` to a `DataFrame` with all rows whose `Gene` columns is in the value of `FunctionsWithGenes[Function]`

For example:

```
>>> FunctionsWithDf['Emotions']
    Gene  Value
0  HAPPY    3.4
1    SAD    4.3
>>> FunctionsWithDf['Singing']
    Gene  Value
0  HAPPY    3.4
```

Comment: Actually is there a way to get the results in a dataframe but duplicate entries for rows that fall within duplicate functions?